# QTreeView contains white boxes in 1st column

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

could someone answer me? why my QTreeView shows white boxes before first column?
I'm using qt.5.6.0.

All methods are default like in official tutorial and there is code of myModel::data():

```
 QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role /*= 
 Qt::DisplayRole*/) const
{
    if (!index.isValid()) {
        return QVariant();
    }

    NodeInfo* nodeInfo = static_cast<NodeInfo*>(index.internalPointer());

    switch (index.column())
    {
    case 0:
    {
        auto name = QString::fromStdString(nodeInfo->getName());       
        return  QVariant(name);
        break;
    }
    case 1:
        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole || role == Qt::EditRole)
        {
            QString data = QString::fromStdString(nodeInfo->getValue());

            return QVariant(data);
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return QVariant();
}
```

[image]

Comment: What does your model's `flags()` function return?

Comment: for 1st column -  Qt::ItemIsSelectable;

Comment: Well, try to use `if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)...` for the first column too.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: updated according to the comments.

The data() method is returning a non-empty QVariant for each role, including **Qt::CheckStateRole**. This was misinterpreted by the QTreeView as a check state.

The fix is to ensure the correct value is returned only for DisplayRole:

```
case 0:
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
         auto name = QString::fromStdString(nodeInfo->getName());       
         return  QVariant(name);
    } else {
         return QVariant();
    }
    break;
}
```

OLD ANSWER:

Most probably, your flags() method returns the Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable flag.

Reimplement the flags method in your model so that the items are not checkable (~Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable). Have a look at the documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags) for more details.

Comment: I've reimplemented it. It returns only qt::Qt::ItemIsSelectable;

Comment: Then in the data() method, return an empty QVariant() for all the other roles except the DisplayRole.